# "Unserer" oder "Unser" als eigenständiges Subjekt

Tags: declension, possessive-pronoun

Als Beispiel folgender Zusammenhang:

> "Unser Fernseher funktioniert nicht mehr."
>
> "Unser(er) auch nicht."

Was ist hier richtig? Ich glaube, ich habe beides schon im Sprachgebrauch gehört. Streng genommen würde ich sagen, dass es *unserer* nur als Verwendung im Genitiv gibt und hier falsch ist. Dafür konnte ich aber bislang keine Bestätigung finden.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Richtig ist m.E. nur „*Unserer*“. „*Unser*“ ist ein [Possessivpronomen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html) (Grundform mask. sing.: „*mein*“). Es kann entweder als Possessivartikel vor einem Nomen stehen:

> „***Unser** Fernseher funktioniert nicht mehr*.“

Es kann aber auch stellvertretend für das Nomen stehen:

> „***Unserer** auch nicht*.“

In diesem Fall ist die [Endung im Nominativ maskulin Singular „**-er**“](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Poss1.html#Anchor-Formen-11481) - also „**unserer**“. Die Form des Possessivpronomens orientiert sich dabei an der Form des Nomens, an dessen Stelle es tritt („*der Fernseher*“).

Es gibt aber auch die Variante des stellvertretenden Possessivpronomens mit Artikel (in der Umgangssprache aber deutlich seltener gebraucht):

> „Unser Fernseher funktioniert nicht mehr.“
>
> „**Der unsere** auch nicht.“

In diesem Fall richtet sich die Endung des Possessovpronomens nach der [schwachen adjektivischen Flexion](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwach.html); im mask. sing. Nominativ also „**-e**“.

Comment: Ausführliche, klare Antwort - Danke!

Comment: Und die Variante "Auslassen eines wiederholten Wortes" geht nicht? Wenn nicht, warum nicht? Im direkten Anschluss empfinde ich "Unser auch nicht" ebenfalls als möglich, weil es einfach kurz für "Unser Fernseher auch nicht" ist.

Comment: @dirkt: Hast Du irgendeine Quelle, die diese Variante ausdrücklich als grammatikalisch zulässig ansieht? Die Variante "stellvertretend für das Nomen" dient gerade der Auslassung eines - ansonsten wiederholten - Wortes. Die [Wikipedia bezeichnet bereits diese Variante als vor allem in der mündlichen Rede gebräuchlich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessivpronomen#Possessive_Ausdr.C3.BCcke_als_Nomen).

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Ich habe nicht nach Quellen gesucht; das wäre meine eigene Erklärung, wenn ich irgendwo "unser auch nicht" gehört habe. Vielleicht ist das ja falsch; deshalb frage ich ja. Ja, ich weiß, dass "unserer" usw. korrekt ist. Aber in diesem Fall ist es keine Auslassung, sonder eine Art Verwendung des Possesivpronomens als Nomen (wie ja der Wikipedia-Link auch beschreibt).

Comment: Ich habe die Dinge eben nochmal anhand des aktuellen Grammatik-Dudens (Bd. 4, 8. Aufl., S. 278 Rn. 370) verifiziert; mehr kann ich nicht dazu sagen. Übrigens: auch der Duden bezeichnet die Variante „*Unserer auch nicht*“ als „elliptische Konstruktion“, bei der das Substantiv zur „Redundanzminimierung“ (so O-Ton Duden) eingespart wird. Die Frage nach dem „warum“ kann ich leider nicht beantworten - so ist einfach die gewachsene Grammatik.

Comment: Auch wenn "unser auch nicht" falsch ist, wird es nach meinem Eindruck umgangssprachlich doch oft so benutzt. Vielleicht weil "unserer" etwas von einem Zungenbrecher hat? - Ansonsten würde ich gerne noch die Alternative "der unsrige" ergänzen (laut Duden "gehoben veraltend").

Comment: @dirkt: Was Wikipedia mit 'Verwendung als Pronomen' meint, ist vermutlich was anderes und in meinen Augen die alte Verwirrung der Nicht-Unterscheidung der determinierenden von den echt pronominalen Formen. Zur Frage selbst würde ich sagen: Möglicherweise gibt es so ein '_unser auch nicht_', nicht jedoch '_mein auch nicht_', was daran liegen könnte, dass das _-(e)r_ von _unser_ als Endung für Nominativ mask. fehlinterpretiert wird - oder es ist ein Gebrauch wie in '_für teuer Geld_ gekauft'. Anders als hier ist es jedoch nicht idiomatisiert, sondern locker umgangssprachlich. Viele würden ...

Comment: ... wertend sagen 'nachlässig'. Ich kann es mir umgangssprachlich vorstellen, würde aber selbst '_unserer_' sagen, obwohl ich stark umgangssprachlich spreche. Interessanterweise ordnet Wikipedia auch die korrekten pronominalen Formen als  'informell'/'familiär' ein, vielleicht, weil sie nur in Dialogen bzw. in mündlichem Sprachgebrauch vorkommen (können?).

Answer (score 3):

Die [im Duden erwähnte Alternative](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unser_Possessivpronomen)

> ***Unsrer*** auch nicht.

verringert die (wahrscheinlich durch das Doppel-*er* in *Unserer* hervorgerufene) Verwirrung m. E. erheblich.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, wie eine Verkürzung die Verwirrung verringern soll … üblicherweise ist das andersrum (d.h. die zusätzliche Silbe verdeutlicht, welches Wort gemeint ist).

Comment: @Jan Ich hatte eine ähnliche Fragestellung wie der OP ("Auf dem Weg zu unser / unserer ersten Veranstaltung ..."), und konnte mir diese selbst nach einigem Nachdenken nicht beantworten. Das meine ich mit "verwirrt". Nachdem ich "unser / unserer" durch "unsrer" ersetzt hatte ("Auf dem Weg zu unsrer ersten Veranstaltung ..."), musste ich nicht weiter nachdenken. Das meine ich mit "verringert die Verwirrung erheblich".

Comment: **Not an answer.**

Comment: @CarstenS **Why not?**

Comment: Ich denke, so eine Verwirrung gibt es tatsächlich, denn hier und da hört man Formen wie '_unserere_', d.h., dass einem gelegentlich die Klarheit der Grenze zwischen Wortstamm und Endung verloren geht. Da wären sich aber wohl alle ernst zu nehmenden _native speaker_ einig, dass das klar falsch ist; bei '_unser auch nicht_' wäre ich mir nicht so sicher, das kann salopp umgangssprachlich sein.