# Why would the pronouns in this sentence have different suffixes?

Tags: gender, possessive-pronoun

Duolingo asked me to translate the following: "is that your thigh or mine?"

I came back with "Ist das dein Oberschenkel oder mein?"

It corrected me with "Ist das dein Oberschenkel oder **meiner**?"

Since both possessive pronouns are referring to the same noun shouldn't their endings agree?

Comment: Related (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/14853/unserer-oder-unser-als-eigenst%c3%a4ndiges-subjekt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English you can say:

> 1. Is that **your** thigh or **my** thigh?
> 2. Is that **your** thigh or **mine**?
> 3. Is that **yours** or **mine**?

And you translate those sentences into German this way:

> 1. Ist das **dein** Oberschenkel oder **mein** Oberschenkel?
> 2. Ist das **dein** Oberschenkel oder **meiner**?
> 3. Ist das **deiner** oder **meiner**?

So you have this pairs:

> your - dein
>   yours - deiner
>   my - mein
>   mine - meiner

Comment: Oberschenkel is masculine and the genitive case would be 'meines'. I think 'meiner' is used in this case as nominative case of the possessive pronoun.

Comment: Wenn ich Wikipedia korrekt verstehe, sind *mein* und *dein* Possessivartikel (englisch *possessive articles*) während nur *meiner* und *deiner* als Possessivpronomen (*possessive pronouns*) zählen. So oder so, der Genitiv wäre *meines* in beiden Fällen.